# anything better than dd to copy disk images to SD card in OS X?

Tags: unix, sudo, sd-card

I have used `dd` because it is what the tutorials suggest to do for instance when copying Linux images to SD cards (e.g. Raspbian, Kali, ...).
This is done at 1 Mb/sec on my macbook pro. I have tried to change the `bs` option of `dd`, e.g. `bs=1m` or `bs=10m` or `bs=100m` but copying a 32 Gb image takes hours and the rate is always around 1 Mb/s.

I read on linux some users suggest to use `cat` instead of `dd` . This seems to not work for me as even with `sudo` I get an error for insufficient permissions.

Just to be clear, the disk partitions are unmounted via

```
sudo diskutil unmount /dev/disk2
sudo diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
```

Also, I should have specified that `dd` works where `cat` is blocked by the permission error.

So my question is, what is the quick and reliable way to copy OS images of tens of Gbytes to a SD card in OS X?

Comment: How is the SD Card reader connected to your Mac?

Comment: make sure the SD Card Volume is unmounted before attempting to use Terminal Commands like `cat` or `dd`

Comment: I should have specified that `dd` works where `cat` is blocked by the permission error. The card is connected via USB-C card reader and with Balana Etcher suggested by @Tony Williams it can be written at 15+ Mb/sec

Comment: How were you using `cat`? If you used something like `sudo cat someimage.iso >/dev/disk2`, the problem is that the redirect is done by the shell, without privilege. See the Unix&Linux question ["Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on) and its answers.

Comment: You got me! I was doing that redirect!

Comment: I have tried `cat file.img | sudo tee /dev/disk2  > /dev/null` but it is super slow, still in progress, but way slower than Balana Etcher

Comment: Another thing occurred to me: try using `dd` with the "raw" device (i.e. `/dev/rdisk2 ` instead of `/dev/disk2`) -- I seem to remember getting a significant speed boost that way.

Comment: `sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk2 of=~/pi20200903.img bs=1m` went much faster
`31878807552 bytes transferred in 1863.624378 secs (17105812 bytes/sec)` so it seems that `rdisk` may be part of the speedup recipe

Comment: the same with `/dev/disk2` today was ` (6332250 bytes/sec)` about three times slower

Answer (score 5):

I use [Balana Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) for my Raspberry Pi SD cards. It's free, fast and even verifies. It's also cross platform.

Comment: This is going so much faster! 20 Mb/sec! Do I understand correctly that it does the job only one way: from file to SD card and not the vice-versa?

Comment: To be honest I've never tried the other way, but I think it only does onto the SD card. Oh, if you think my solution is your answer you should mark it correct.

Comment: I would, it that would replace entirely `dd`, but I am afraid it does not because I do not see how `Etcher` can write from the SD to a file. I am trying `Disk Utility` right now but it does not react to `File> New Image>Image From "diskname"`.  I have tried to unmount the partition using the GUI of Disk Utility but seems to make no difference.